# Is $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x}$ a polynomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials

My book mentions that in a polynomial function, there cannot be any x-terms in the denominator; however, they didn't give any explanation as to why. My hunch is that if there are any x-related terms in the denominator, the denominator could become 0 for some value of x, and the function would become undefined.

For example,

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x}$$

Is that why the book tells me to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That function is called a rational function, and it is not a polynomial. Rational functions do have the problem that they may be undefined at certain points.

Polynomials are functions of the form
$$
f(x) =a_0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n.
$$
These functions are well-behaved and exhibit many interesting properties (continuous, differentiable, integrable, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There can’t be $x$ terms at the nominator its a matter of definition, polynomial functions are indeed by definition in the form

$$p_n(x)=a_0+a_1x*\ldots+a_nx^n$$

and a key property for polynomial functions is that they are defined over all $\mathbb R$ which of course could be lost for rational functions

$$f(x)=\frac{p_n(x)}{q_n(x)}$$

but not necessarily, as for example for $q_n(x)=x^2+1$.